# Remove UICollectionView for size class

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uicollectionview, interface-builder

I have a `ViewController`, Inside it I have a `UICollectionView`, I need it to be installed for `Any X Any` but I don't need it for the `Regular X Any`.

I've removed it and it is grey when I work on the `Regular X Any` size class, but when I run, the `delegate` and `DataSource` are still connecting and asking for cells, and the `IBOutlet` for it is not nil.

I'm adding a picture of my setup[image: Setup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably DO run on a Regular X Any traits environment without knowing.   Double check while debugging your app.

Comment: I am running on iPad, why would it be and other trait collection than `Regular X Any`?

Comment: Master-details controllers?
The VC on the master (left) side of the screen have a Regular X Any trait collection.